E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.sources (Suite)
I recently upgraded to ubuntu 24.04.  When I run apt update I get the error:  Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.sources (Suite)
How can I resolve this?


"Suites" needs a value

Please don't post images of text. Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the formatting tools to format it as code.

Note: Ubuntu 24.04 with Ubuntu Pro, and snapd purged.
What you show in the image (do NOT paste text as images!)
and what I have in the same file differs a bit, which may be due to differing settings...
But: create a backup copy of your file, and place a copy of mine in its original place.
This might help you get further.
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.sources 
# Written by ubuntu-pro-client
Types: deb
URIs: https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu
Suites: noble-infra-security
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-pro-esm-infra.gpg

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.sources
# Written by ubuntu-pro-client
Types: deb
URIs: https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu
Suites: noble-apps-security
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-pro-esm-apps.gpg


can you share the file for app.sources too?

I assume you by that mean the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - which specific one is it you would need?

I would need this one
vansh@vansh:~$ nl /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.sources
1 # Written by ubuntu-pro-client
2 Types: deb deb-src
3 URIs: https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu
4 Suites:
5 Components: main
6 Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-pro-esm-apps.gpg

Added above: One note of caution, I have purged snapd (I have so far found snap packages to be annoyingly "non-integrated" in the OS) which MIGHT be reflected by only deb being present on the Types: line above.
